# Whats the importance of yartzeit?

Tags: minhag, calendar, death, yahrtzeit

What is the significance of the date of a yartzeit (anniversary of a death)? Is there anything really special about the anniversary of someone's death or is it just an emotional event - a chance to remember the deceased?

Comment: The Talmud doesn't mention it. Many Rishonim too don't mention it. It can't be _that_ big a deal fundamentally if much of the Jewish world didn't know about it for most of time.

Comment: You can find sources; especially later ones that make a big deal about everything. What sort of sources are you looking for? How are we supposed to differentiate much ado about nothing, from something substantial

Comment: @mevaqesh. If you can't, then just don't answer. I put it out there cause I can't either and I'm hoping somebody else will be able to.

Comment: It is impossible unless you tell us what sort of sources you are looking for. Me personally deciding certain sources are bunk is not an answer unless I do so following criteria specified in the OP. | For example, it is hard to know whether the current answer suffices. Someone impressed by the sources would claim it does. Someone unimpressed would claim it does not. The only way to render the question answerable is to specify what sort of sources you are willing to accept. (Although at this point you can't invalidate the existing answer).

Comment: @DoubleAA. Are there really any Rishonim that mention it as an important event? Or is just in passing like "the hamon Am does so and so..." ?

Answer (score 2):

[Nitei Gavriel Aveilus 2 - 70:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=532&hilite=) says that the Neshama gets judged on the day of the Yahrzheit. He quotes this in the name of the Arizal - Shaar Hakavanos, Lechem Hapanim 376, Mishmeres Shalom in the name of the Baal Shem Tov, Sh"ut Torah Lishma 493, Nishmas Chaim and others.

Comment: Judged for what? It was already judged when it died.

Comment: @DoubleAA: My answer may not be 100% as I am writing based on what I recall hearing many years ago in a Shiur. When one creates a Kiddush Hashem or a Chillul Hashem or does a Mitzva or an Aveira, often there is residual value to what was done. For example one makes a Kiddush Hashem and someone becomes religious and starts doing Mitzvos, then marries and raises a Torah true family, or one creates a Chilul Hashem and through that one becomes lax with Mitzvos or refuses to help another Jew.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways people celebrate a YorTzeit. One of the ways as done in Yeshivas is to have a shiur in honor of the deceased. This is based on an ancient practice as seen in Rashi in Yevamos top of 122a. He quotes the Gaonim that having the Talmudic academies assemble at the grave of a Rabbi on the anniversary of his death was a way to honor him.

> תלתא ריגלי - שהיו תלמידי חכמים נקבצים לשמוע דרשה הלכות פסח בפסח והיתה שואלת מהם. ובתשובת הגאונים מצאתי כל הנך ריגלי דאמוראי היינו יום שמת בו אדם גדול קובעים אותו לכבודו ומדי שנה בשנה כשמגיע אותו יום מתקבצים תלמידי חכמים מכל סביביו ובאים על קברו עם שאר העם להושיב ישיבה שם:

It seems this was more in line of what you would call an emotional anniversary than anything else. There are no hidden reasons alluded to.

Comment: Why learning at the grave is allowed is discussed in various tshuvos brought in Shearim mitzuyanim bihalacha.

Comment: Consider too BK 16b וכבוד עשו לו במותו and perhaps a parallel AZ 8a יום המיתה

Comment: @Double Ty. Yes. They were considered. However B.K. is apparently only the actual day of death, not a yearly occurrence. A.Z. Is about a nonjewish king's yortzeit. Are you making some deaper correlation that I'm missing?

Comment: Just that it's a known form of respect. Standing up for someone, not using their first name, etc. aren't specifically Jewish ways of showing respect, and this need not be either. והראיה we see even non-Jews doing it too. Just a thought....

Comment: @Double Gotcha. That's what I thought you might have meant as I was typing.  I think that is a very good point actually.

Comment: Though surprisingly it doesn't seem to have survived much in western cultures/religions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_anniversary